# Как добавить фотографию в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlabel, qpixmap

Пытаюсь добавить фотографию таким способом:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Photos")

image = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(QtGui.QPixmap("colors.png"))
image.setOffset(300, 300)

label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setPixmap(image)

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label)

window.setLayout(layout)

window.setGeometry(500,500,500,500)
window.show()

sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Выдает ошибку

```
File "c:\Program Files\Python38\pyproj\qpixmap2.py", line 13, in <module>
    label.setPixmap(image)
TypeError: setPixmap(self, QPixmap): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QGraphicsPixmapItem'
```

Понимаю в чем заключается ошибка, но не понимаю как ее исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore  # + QtCore

application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Photos")

#image = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(QtGui.QPixmap("colors.png"))     # ---
#image.setOffset(300, 300)                                              # ---
image = QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(300, 300)                        # +++ <<<-------  

label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)                               # +
label.setPixmap(image)

layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label)

window.setLayout(layout)

window.setGeometry(500,500,500,500)
window.show()

sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]